# Networked Aframe project not working with dynamic-rooms

Tags: javascript, networking, three.js, aframe, aframe-networked

I have a project I'm creating using A-frame (https://aframe.io) and the networked A-frame component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/networked-aframe

Link to the project: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/networkedtest

I've run into an issue where whenever I try to replace the following code in **scene.html on line 202**:

```
<a-scene moving-sun vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;" physics networked-scene="
      room: audio;
      adapter: easyrtc;
      audio: true;
      video: true;
      debug: true;
      inspector=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe-inspector@master/dist/aframe-inspector.min.js">
```

With this code:

```
<a-scene moving-sun vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;" physics dynamic-room="
      room: audio;
      adapter: easyrtc;
      audio: true;
      video: true;
      debug: true;
      inspector=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe-inspector@master/dist/aframe-inspector.min.js">
```

The entire code doesn't run properly and I get a blank white screen.

I'm not sure at all why this is, since all I'm doing is replacing the `networked-scene=""` line with `dynamic-room=""` but I still get a plane white screen. What I'm wondering is how **inside the scene.html file on line 202,** I can replace the first snippet of code with the second and have to code run properly.

If anybody knows why this issue is occurring, help would be very much appreciated.

**Link to the project:**  https://glitch.com/edit/#!/networkedtest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check the console and try fixing any issue that you find there.

One of them is:

[image]

From what I see, You do:

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var myNametag = player.querySelector(".nametag");
myNametag.setAttribute("text", "value", username);
```

In your `scene.html`, so there is no need to do the same in the `dynamic-room` component. Once you remove this bit from the `dynamic-room` it all works. So either remove it, or check why it's duplicated

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly!